# Does 以安倍的自民党为首的联盟 use the 以 ~ 为 pattern?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase

According to [the following sentence](https://www.voachinese.com/a/news-japan-election-20171022/4081156.html):

> 日本一家电视台的民调显示，**以安倍的自民党为首的联盟**将保持三分之二的“绝对多数”，与安倍九月份解散议会下院之前的比例相当。

The bold sentence starts with 以, and it also has 为. So at first I assumed it is 以～为 pattern, which is "regarding A as B" or "taking A as B" in English.

However, I also found that 为首 means "serve as the head", and it should exactly refer to 安倍. And I understand the meaning then.

So is this sentence 以～为 pattern or not? If not, what does the leading 以 mean and work in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [**以**][安倍的自民党][**为**][首][的联盟] fits the pattern of [**with**][A] [**as**] [B]

"首" is short for "首领",

[A - 安倍的自民党] = [B - 首领]

- '为'+'首(领)' simply means 'as leader' (preposition + noun)
- '**为首**' as a set phrase, is a common adjective "**leading**/ **top ranked**"

Example:

'在这次会议上, **为首**官员是北京市长'-- 'In this meeting, the **leading** (top ranked) officer is Beijing mayor'

Comment: Actually, my macOS pre-installed dictionary and Pleco both list 为首 as a verb, and mean "serve as the head".

Comment: But I just found that in both dictionaries, the example sentences both use 以～为 pattern. 以总统为首的代表团 & 以外交部长为首的代表团

Comment: the verb is '以' (use/ take); '为首' is  (preposition + noun)

Comment: So in these two example sentences is it not 以~为 pattern?

Comment: 以总统为首的代表团 & 以外交部长为首的代表团 are both [ 以 (A ) 为( B)] structure--  [总统 ( A)] = [首领 (B) ]; [外交部长 (A) ] = [首领 (B)]

Comment: But for some reasons these two sentences are listed as an example sentence for the entry for the word 为首, and both list 为首 as a verb; it sounds awkward...

Comment: See my example of the the  difference between '为'+'首' (preposition + noun) = "as leader"  and '为首' (adjectival phrase)= "leading"

Comment: @Blaszard, 为首 indeed is a verb or a verb phrase, although we might translate it as a prep word 'as' in English. In 以...为首， 以 is a prep(though we could translate it as 'take' in English)， 为 is a verb and 首 is a noun. The way to differentiate whether 为 is a verb or prep is that it's pronounced as second tone *wei2* when it's a verb, fourth tone *wei4* when it's a prep.

Comment: @dan 为 can be a verb in other context, but following  以, 为 is acting as a preposition,

Comment: 为 in '为首' in a verb, but '为首'  as a whole, is an 'adjectival phrase, as in '为首數人都是專家'

Comment: @TangHo, No, 为首 indeed is a verb or a verb phrase, because it's pronounced as the second tone 'wei2'. In 为首数人， it is used as an attributive, and it's like saying 为首的数人. Another example for a verb as an attributive is 喜欢（a verb）, 喜欢的人。 So, 为首之人 vs 喜欢之人.

Comment: @TangHo, 以...为首 is the same as 为首, in which 为 is a verb. for example, 我们以他为首， 以他 is a prep phrase, 为 is the verb, 我们 is the subject, 首 is the object.

Answer (score 1):

以～为: take...as...

In 为首， 首 means head or leader, while 为 means as.

For example, 以瘦为美：take thin as beauty; 以他为首： take him as leader;

So, 以安倍的自民党为首: take 安倍的自民党 as leader. 以安倍的自民党为首的 is attributive to modify 联盟. 安倍的自民党 is the head.

Comment: Surely I know the 以~为 phrase. So according to your answer, in this sentence is it not 为首 but just 首 that modifies 自民党?

Comment: Also, is it a valid sentence to duplicate 为, such that 以安倍的自民党为为首的?

Comment: Or put it in another way, my question is: Is it [ **以** (安倍的自民党) **为** (首)的]联盟 (以～为 modifies 联盟), or is it **以** [(安倍的自民党为首)的]联盟 (安倍的自民党为首 modifies 联盟)?

Comment: it should be 【（以 安倍的自民党 为 首）的】联盟. "以安倍的自民党为为首的?" is wrong, and only one 为 is needed. 以安倍的自民党为首的

Comment: 自民党 is modified by 安倍 的

Comment: But doesn't 为首 also mean "leader" or "head"? So I wonder if it is OK to say 以安倍的自民党为为首的 as well...

Comment: I told you already 以安倍的自民党为为首的 is wrong. So, it's either used as 以... 为首 or 为首. For example, 为首的人是他。；以他为首;

Comment: Actually, 首 means leader or head, while 为 means 'as'. So, 为首：as leader.